# Error while starting sproutcore server uninitialized constant SproutCore::Rack::Proxy

Tags: sproutcore

Issued sc-server command from the app and i got the above error. Using fixures in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you Sproutcore install is messed up.  Are you using the latest version of Ruby, and are the Gems all updated?